# How to send parameter value to controller from Multi-column Dropdown Selector plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using a [multi-column dropdown selector plugin](https://www.inputpicker.com/) in my MVC project. I am trying to send the company id (`$('#Company').val()`) as a parameter in the URL. The problem is that the value is always `null` in the controller.

If I send a hardcoded value like `url: '@Url.Action("ReturnProduct", "Product")?Id=12345'` then the company id can be traced.

It's probably a jQuery function is not working here. Is there any method for sending dynamic values to the controller?

```js
$('#Product').inputpicker({
  url: '@Url.Action("ReturnProduct", "Product")?Id=' + $('#Company').val(),
  fields: [{
    name: 'Id',
    text: 'Id'
  }, {
    name: 'ProductName',
    text: 'Name'
  }, {
    name: 'PTax',
    text: 'PTax'
  }],
});
```

Comment: Your `initpicker` only runs once; when the inputpicker is first initialised.  You state "*for sending dynamic values*" - so if your `#Company` element is an `input` or a `select` then the url won't be updated dynamically when the company changes.

Comment: If your #Company element is not user selectable, then you can set it from the model, assuming your (provided) js in a in `<script>` tag in the .cshtml (as you're using `@Url`) then `url: '@Url.Action(...)?Id=@Model.CompanyId',`

Comment: Can you confirm your `inputpicker` plugin source?  Found one at https://www.inputpicker.com/ the limited documentation doesn't provide a way to *update* the url.  You might be able call `$('#Product').inputpicker({ url: ..new url...`}) (without other parameters) on the #Company change event, but it may recreate the picker.  Would have to check the source to confirm.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am using the same plugin and every keystroke inputpicker hits the controller i.e. database. Is it possible to create the data source once in the memory?

Comment: Use a different picker... :)